# Получить из IP имя узла (java)

Tags: java

В локальном чате при выводе сообщения пользователя необходимо вместо IP-адреса выводить имя удаленного узла. Есть ли методы получить из IP имя узла? (Java)

Comment: Reverse DNS lookup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам может помочь [InetAddress.getHostName()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName--)

Comment: А какого типа `ipAddr`?

Comment: @Qwertiy справедливо!

Comment: То что вывело WIN-SVSHC2AJLP9 , а должно быть "User"

Comment: @Bigniggaboss компьютер, с которого было сделано подключение, называется User?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev , да, именно так

Comment: Значит стоит проверить настройки DNS-сервера.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, не совсем понимаю, как это связано

Comment: @Bigniggaboss, вообще-то я тоже не верю, что компьютер называется `User`. Выполни на нём (а можешь ещё и на сервере) команды `ping User` и `ping WIN-SVSHC2AJLP9` - какая из них работает, а какая завершается ошибкой `Ping request could not find host User. Please check the name and try again.`?

Comment: Метод `getHostName()` обращается к dns-клиенту операционной системы, тот в свою очередь делает запрос dns-серверу, а dns-сервер возвращает имя связанное с данным IP-адресом. Если возвращает не то имя, значит есть с ним проблемы.

Comment: Действительно, вы были правы. Спасибо большое)

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, а если нужно получить имя учетной записи пользователя. По аналогии System.getProperty("user.name") только не текущего а удаленного узла ?

Comment: Это невозможно. Удалённый узел должен сам передать серверу эту информацию каким-либо образом.

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev, понял, спасибо)